# No module named 'datetime' for code deployed on aws lambda

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-datetime

I have a python code deployed on aws lambda. The code uses this code:

```
datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

I am using `import datetime` in the beginning of the file. But when I deploy this code on Lambda, I get this error: `No module named datetime`

`datetime` is a part of python so it should be imported in aws on its own which is strange. How can I fix this? What package I should add?

I tried adding datetime.py in aws lambda package with code files but then it throws  `nonetype' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Please guide!

UPDATE: Attached info below-

LOGS: 
[image]

Files whose zip package is made
[image: Zip Structure]

Pasting just the lambda handler code, (with names and slight modifications, tried to maintain the general flow)

```
import sys
import json
import traceback
import os
import datetime
from dynamo_db_helper import DynamoDBHelper
from api_helper import ApiHelper
from google_drive_helper import GoogleDriveHelper
from sflogger import Logger


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        id = event["Id"]
        set_config(id)

        val1 = event["key1"]
        val2 = event["key2"]
        val3 = event["key3"]
        val4 = event["key4"]
        val5 = event["key5"]
        val6 = event["key6"]
        val7 = event["key7"]
        val8 = event["key8"]
        val9 = event["key9"]
        val10 = stop_session_url.replace("/stopsession", "/verify/")

        db_helper = DynamoDBHelper(URL, DYNAMO_DB_METADATA_TABLE_NAME, stream_id)
        data = db_helper.get_item_from_db(id)

        if data is not None \
                and data['LastModifiedTime'] < datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30):
            link = data["Link"]
        else:
            if data is not None \
                    and data['Time'] > datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30):
                db_helper.delete_item_from_db(id)

            link = perform_this(event, db_helper, val10)

        if link is None:
            response = set_fail("error_message")
            return response

        response = set_success(link)
        return response

    except Exception as e:
        response = set_fail("error_message")
        return response


def set_fail(msg):
    response = {"status": "Google Editing session Failed", "message": msg}
    return json.dumps(response)


def set_success(link):
    response = {"status": "Success", "webViewLink": webViewLink}
    return json.dumps(response)
```

Let me know if anything is needed

Comment: I posted code that works - how are you deploying the lambda function?

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n   I am creating a zip file of all the packages required and uploading the zip. It throws 'No module named datetime'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works.

```
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  print(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30))
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It throws 'No module named datetime'.

Comment: @Atihska -- Could you please show us the code you tried using (based on Justin's example) and the error message returned? Also, please let us know the filename within the zip file.

Comment: I took Justin's code, put it into a Zip file (with just the .py file, without `datetime.py`), created a Lambda function, uploaded the Zip file to the Lambda function, then tested it. It worked fine. I wonder if your problem is that you are not calling the correct 'main' file first? You might want to start with something simple to figure out what's going wrong with your full deployment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sorry for the delay in reply. I was able to fix the issue. The problem was that in one of the file I was using import datetime.datetime. But the correct code and your options to look for, helped me debug the issue.